# Force usage of DNS server provided by DHCP?

Tags: debian, dns, dhcp

I got a preconfigured debian image that gets it's network configuration by DHCP, however the DNS server is/was fixed to 8.8.8.8. This was configured using /etc/resolv.conf, so I deleted all the entries there. /etc/dhcpc/resolv.conf contains the DNS server I would like to use, however this DNS server isn't used by the system. How do I activate the usage of the DNS server provided by DHCP? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up installing `isc-dhcp-client`, seems to fix the problem. Thanks for all the other hints, though!

Answer (score 1):

ln -sf /etc/dhcpc/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf

Explanation:

The system will look *only* in /etc/resolv.conf for nameservers. What the above command does is it creates a symbolic link /etc/resolv.conf to the file /etc/dhcpc/resolv.conf. In effect, when opening /etc/resolv.conf you actually open the file /etc/dhcpc/resolv.conf. And I take it that file contains the information you want your system to use.

Comment: thanks for your reply, nice idea that would do the job. What I am wodnering about: is this the default way how it's done in common linux distributions?

Comment: @stefan.at.wpf for debian install the `resolvconf` package

Comment: Nowadays in most common linux distributions network related stuff is managed by the "network-manager". The network manager modifies the file /etc/resolv.conf and fills it with whatever it thinks should be in there. In the past tools like dhclient and alike used to write to /etc/resolv.conf directly.